# Upgrading from 6.06 LTS to 10.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Have dapper on a server currently and would like to upgrade yet when I have tried system become unstable and I have to revert back to original image.  Installing on VA Linux Systems 1000 server (FYI 2000).  Monitor goes out of range with upgrade attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can upgrade from 6.06 LTS to 10.04 LTS. You have to upgrade to 8.04 LTS first, than upgrade to 10.04 LTS. [Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardyUpgrades#Upgrade_from_6.06_LTS_to_8.04_LTS)